# react unable to render anything

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, typescript, web

I am trying to create a personal website using, typescript, react, and nodejs. I have written a few basic lines of code just to check if my code renders anything or not. On running, I realized that nothing was being rendered on the react app. I am not sure why this is happening.
I have attached the neccessary documents regarding this. It would be great if someone could help me?

Code for Index.js [which runs]

```
export { default } from './GlobalStyles';
```

Code for Package.json in the @mui in the node_modules

```
{
  "sideEffects": false,
  "module": "./index.js",
  "main": "../node/GlobalStyles/index.js",
  "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

Code for site.tsx, which the dom element I have added and is to be rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
//import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { design } from './site-style';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

export default function siteContent() {
  const classes = design();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.text}>
        <Button variant='contained' className={classes.green}> Hi </Button>
      </div>
      <div>

      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Code for the site-styles to style the site

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material';

export const design = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  },
  navbar: {
    border: '20px solid black'
  }, 
  green: { 
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    color: 'white',
    border: 'black'
  }
  

})
)
```

The Package.json file with all the dependencies

```
{
  "name": "archit_website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.44",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6"
  }
}
```

I am actually unable to understand why is anything not rendering. Also, suggest me if it is a good decision to create a website using the current format instead of using classic HTML,CSS,JS. Kindly Suggest. I have also attached the screenshots of the files in VS code.
Have a look if needed.

[package.json inside @mui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2kuJ.png)

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNPvL.png)

[site-style.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w0qx.png)

[site.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3GLk.png)

Comment: Do you ever call `ReactDOM.createRoot`?

Comment: Now, if I think of it I didn't

Comment: But, I am new to this would be able to suggest me how and where I could call it/use dom?

Comment: This documentation might help: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/add-react-to-a-website#step-4-add-your-react-component-to-the-page